# How to get the number of tweets from a hastag in python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, hashtag

I am trying to get the number of tweets containing a hashtag (let's say "#kitten") in python.

I am using tweepy.

However, all the codes I have found are in this form :

```
query = "kitten"

for i, status in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(50)):
    print(i, status)
```

I have this error : 'API' object has no attribute 'search'

Tweepy seemed to not cointain this object anymore. Is there any way to answer my problem ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5):

After browsing the web and twitter documentation I found the answer.

If you want the historic of all tweet counts from 2006 you need Academic authorization. This is not my case so I can only get 7 days tracking which is enough in my case. Here is the code :

```
import tweepy

query = "kitten -is:retweet"
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)
counts = client.get_recent_tweets_count(query=query, granularity='day')

for i in counts.data:
    print(i["tweet_count"])
```

The `"-is:retweet"` is here to not count the retweets. You need to remove it if you want to count them.

Since we're not pulling any tweets (only the volume of them) we are not increasing our MONTHLY TWEET CAP USAGE.

Be carefull when using symbols in your query such as "$" it might give you an error. For a list of valid operators see : [list of valid operators for query](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product)

As said here [Twitter counts introduction](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/introduction), you only need "read only" authorization to perform a recent count request. (see Recent Tweet counts)