# How to get the number of tweets from a hastag in python between two timestamps

Tags: python, tweepy

[How to get the number of tweets from a hastag in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437763/how-to-get-the-number-of-tweets-from-a-hastag-in-python)

The link above shows how to retrieve tweet count per day, but I would like to retrieve a count between two given timeframes for example between 12am and 11pm.

How do I do that:

```
import tweepy

query = "kitten"
client = tweepy.Client("<token>")
counts = client.get_recent_tweets_count(query=query, granularity='hours')#


for i in counts.data:
    print(i["tweet_count"])
```

This is what i have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API documentation give you all the possible granularities [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/api-reference/get-tweets-counts-recent).

> #### Query parameters
>
> **granularity** (string) : this is the granularity that you want the timeseries count data to be grouped by. You can requeset [yes, there is a typo in the documentation] `minute`, `hour`, or `day` granularity. The default granularity, if not specified is `hour`.